# Where can I learn the lingo of Go?

Tags: go, terminology

I'm only a beginner at Go, but have been reading the questions in the [go](/questions/tagged/go) tag with interest.

However, this game seems to have rather more special terminology than most. What do `joseki`, `shimari`, `high-point`, `pincer`, `aji keshi`, `fuseki`, `komi`, `moyo`, `tsumego` etc. mean?

Could someone explain these terms, or is there a good glossary somewhere that I could consult to help me understand these conversations?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Most of the special terminology of Go is just Japanese Go terms adopted by English-speaking players.  Depending on who you're dealing with, you can be just as likely to see references to *"shimari"* and *"fuseki"* as you are to see "corner enclosures" and "the opening".

A good beginner's resource for learning Go can be found at [Sensei's Library](http://senseis.xmp.net).  In particular, they have [a page dedicated to common Go terminology](http://senseis.xmp.net/?CommonGoTerms).